# How to create/hide javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have code:

```html
<a href='' type="button" class="<?php if($row->status==0) { echo 'btn btn-circle blue btn-sm hidden';} else { echo 'btn btn-circle blue btn-sm';}?>">View</a>
```

How to change code above with Javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Use [jquery click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work (i assumed you have multiple items)

Your view:

```
<a href='' type="button" data-status="<?=$row->status; ?>" class="btn btn-circle blue btn-sm">View</a>
```

the js Code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a.btn.btn-circle").each(function(index)  {
        if ($(this).attr("data-status") == 1)   $(this).addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

ok here an updated answer with the whole script
you'll see the "not view" button is hidden - because he has
`data-status="1"`

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("a.btn.btn-circle").each(function(index)  {
        if ($(this).attr("data-status") == 1)   $(this).addClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
  <a href='' type="button" data-status="1" class="btn btn-circle blue btn-sm">not View</a>
<a href='' type="button" data-status="0" class="btn btn-circle blue btn-sm">View</a>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: in order to help you, i need the type of error you get ;)

Comment: i updated the answer with the whole code, and you'll see it works

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like this to click and hide

```js
$("#view").hide();
$("#toggle").click(function(){
$("#view").toggle();
})
$("#view").click(function(){
$("#view").hide();
})


$("#Show").click(function(){

$("#view").show();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toggle">
Toggle to show or hide
</div>

<div id="Show">
Show
</div>
<div id="view">
Hide
</div>
```